# Cover background not filling screen when screen is bigger than image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have got a background image which is 1920x1080. I want to resize and center this image to fill the screen and be centered **at all times**. I have used two different approaches:

1:

```
.background{
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

2:

```
.background{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Both work on my desktop computer, which has a resolution of 1280x1024 (Yeah, they still exist). But when I view this page on my mobile phone, which has a resolution of 1920x10180, in portrait, the image does not fill the entire screen.

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQLLK.jpg)
[Mobile phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28vAY.jpg)

As you can see the image does not fill the screen as supposed to on my mobile phone. Does `cover` not fill the screen when it is bigger than the image itself? If so, how can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Full style of `.background`:

```
.background{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center center;
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    z-index: 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:** 
I generate a random image to be the `background` of `<div class="background></div>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = 5;
    var rand;
    var setImage = false;

    function randomIntFromInterval(min,max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
    }

    //Generate random image
    if(!setImage){
        rand = randomIntFromInterval(1, NUMBER_OF_IMAGES);
        document.getElementById('background').style.background = 'url(img/' + rand + '.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed';
    }       
</script>
```

Comment: android default browser on your phone?

Comment: Yes it is, is that the problem? Well, it is Chrome. That was default on my phone. Downloading FF now to test.

Comment: @ShanRobertson With FF this happens as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With background-size:cover, the background images fills up the whole area. Your mobile screenshot really looks like you have applied background-size:contain.

Comment: I am sure I use `cover`. I do not know why it acts like this.

Comment: And if you resize your desktop browser, does it act the same way as on your mobile?

Comment: The `input`s dobresize, they het bigger as intended. The background image fills the complete screen. I think the problem is the fact that the image's height smaller is than the screens height on my phone.

Comment: The image size does nothing to do with it if you have background-size: cover. The image will scale up normally even if it is too small. Can you please add more styles to your question regarding the element with the .background class.

Comment: OK just saw the updated answer. I just tested and it acts normal. Is the background image inline in the markup?

Comment: What do you mean with `inline`? `display:inline;` or something else?

Comment: How do you add the image similar to this? <section class="background" style="background-image: url('image.jpg')"></section>

Comment: Oh, in that way. No, I have a `<div class="background"></div>`. But the image is generated by JavaScript, will include in question

Comment: How does the image come in if it is not defined in the background class?

Comment: Try to put "cover" in the script where you define the random image

Comment: The background property can overwrite the styles you do not define so it is better to define cover here as well document.getElementById('background').style.background = 'url(img/' + rand + '.jpg) no-repeat center center cover fixed';

Comment: I added `document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundSize = 'cover';` and it worked. Thank you very much for your help. Now the background does fill my whole phone screen.

Answer (score 1):

In your JS you use the `background` shorthand property, which not only sets the URL/repeat/position, but also overwrites the `background-size` property you originally defined in your CSS, with the default property.

Try adding a line to your JS to "reset" the `background-size` after dynamically updating the background:

```
document.getElementById('background').style.background = 'url(img/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed';
document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
```

Also in your code you use `getElementById` but have a class selector in CSS

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2vnasec5/